# CUnit assertion Assertion `((void *)0) != f_pCurSuite' failed

Tags: c, unit-testing, cunit

My code looks like this:

```
#include <CUnit/CUnit.h>


int maxi(int i1, int i2)
{
    return (i1 > i2) ? i1 : i2;
}

void test_maxi(void)
{
    CU_ASSERT(maxi(0,2) == 2);
}

int main() {
    test_maxi();
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it using `gcc test.c -o test -lcunit` on Ubuntu.

I get this error when trying to launch it:

> test: TestRun.c:159: CU_assertImplementation: Assertion `((void *)0)
>   != f_pCurSuite' failed. Aborted (core dumped)

What does it mean? I found nothing about it on the internet.

Comment: Have you checked [the example code](http://cunit.sourceforge.net/example.html)? It seems you are missing quite a lot of setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUnit works on test suites, you need to create before you can run the application.

A very basic way to make your test to work is like the following:

```
#include <CUnit/CUnit.h>
#include <CUnit/Basic.h>

int maxi(int i1, int i2)
{
    return (i1 > i2) ? i1 : i2;
}

void test_maxi(void)
{
    CU_ASSERT(maxi(0,2) == 2);
}

int main() {
    CU_initialize_registry();
    CU_pSuite suite = CU_add_suite("maxi_test", 0, 0);

    CU_add_test(suite, "maxi_fun", test_maxi);

    CU_basic_set_mode(CU_BRM_VERBOSE);
    CU_basic_run_tests();
    CU_cleanup_registry();

    return 0;
}
```

without all the required checks, but as Joachim Pileborg suggested in the comments, it's safer to follow the example code provided.